# SELECT query with querystring parameters using NULL value

Tags: asp.net, select, null, query-string

Hello to all respected members,

Presently I using following SELECT command in asp.net for populating a Gridview based on Query string values:

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Date, Train, I_R, Dir_Ind, Detn, Rly, DiV, Loco, Shed, locoClass, loco_type FROM PunctualityMain WHERE Date &gt;= @strdt AND Date &lt;= @enddt AND ([Rly] = @rly OR @rly IS NULL) AND ([shed] = @shed OR @shed IS NULL) Order by Date ASC">

 <SelectParameters>
 <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="strdt" QueryStringField="strdt" Type="DateTime" />
 <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="enddt" QueryStringField="enddt" Type="DateTime" />
 <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="rly" QueryStringField="rly" Type="string" />
 <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="shed" QueryStringField="shed" Type="string" />
 </SelectParameters>
```

It is working fine also with two values null as :

```
  http://elocos.railnet.gov.in/Punctuality/Punctualitydetail.aspx?strdt=5/1/2013&enddt=5/14/2013&rly=&shed=
```

Now I want to use same for Gridview with Delete, Insert & Update Commands which is as under:

```
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [PunctualityMain] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [PunctualityMain] ([Date], [Train], [Dir_Ind], [Detn], [Rly], [DiV], [Loco], [Shed], [locoClass], [loco_type]) VALUES (@Date, @Train, @Dir_Ind, @Detn, @Rly, @DiV, @Loco, @Shed, @locoClass, @loco_type)" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PunctualityMain] WHERE (([Date] &gt;= @strdt) AND ([Date] &lt;= @enddt) AND ([Shed] = @shed OR @shed IS NULL) AND ([Rly] = @rly OR @rly IS NULL)) ORDER BY [Date]"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [PunctualityMain] SET [Date] = @Date, [Train] = @Train, [Dir_Ind] = @Dir_Ind, [Detn] = @Detn, [Rly] = @Rly, [DiV] = @DiV, [Loco] = @Loco, [Shed] = @Shed, [locoClass] = @locoClass, [loco_type] = @loco_type WHERE [ID] = @ID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Train" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Dir_Ind" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Detn" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Rly" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DiV" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Loco" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Shed" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="locoClass" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loco_type" Type="String" />
       </InsertParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
   <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="strdt" QueryStringField="strdt" Type="DateTime" />
   <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="enddt" QueryStringField="enddt" Type="DateTime" />
   <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="rly" QueryStringField="rly" Type="string" />
   <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="shed" QueryStringField="shed" Type="string" />
   </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Train" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Dir_Ind" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Detn" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Rly" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DiV" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Loco" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Shed" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="locoClass" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="loco_type" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
```

Why the above SELECT command not working with NULL values for rly & shed? However, with all the four query string values it is working like this

```
  http://elocos.railnet.gov.in/Punctuality/Punctualitydetail.aspx?strdt=5/1/2013&enddt=5/14/2013&rly=CR&shed=KYN
```

Please suggest any solution for the problem so that it can work with this string also (NULL string values)

```
  http://elocos.railnet.gov.in/Punctuality/Punctualitydetail.aspx?strdt=5/1/2013&enddt=5/14/2013&rly=&shed=
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you get Empty value from empty querystring value =/= null

In order to get this working you should set null value manually.
I can suggest you at least 2 ways:

1) In codebehind:

```
string rly = Request.QueryString["rly"];
if (rly == "")
rly = null;
```

And then use it.

2) In SQL command:

```
Rly=NullIf('@rly','')
```

But I'm not sure if 2nd one will work like this, if it won't then you can try to workaround it like:

codebehind `string empt = "";`

SQL command `Rly=NullIf('@rly','+empt+')`

Or you can go some other way, the point is to verify it "rly" query is "", if it is then set it to null, otherwise leave it alone.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error you get? If you don't get an error then give some example on what you're trying to achieve, for example your case - you are selecting everything from table where strdt=5/1/2013, enddt=5/14/2013, rly=null ,shed=null and you want return from table lines with values strdt=5/1/2013, enddt=5/14/2013, rly=Anything ,shed=Anything, is this correct?

Comment: I'll not be checking this for a while, if the above is correct, you can try it like:(@rly IS NULL AND Rly IS NULL)OR(@rly IS NOT NULL AND Rly =@rly)